# selecting a table cell based on its id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the table set up as

```
<table class="tab1" width="400" cellpadding="20">
     <tr>
         <td id="cell1">Name</td>
         <td id="cell2">Company</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

It is being accessed using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         if($('#cell1').attr('click',true)) {
             alert("Cell 1 was clicked");
         }
     });     
</script>
```

I want the alert message to display when the cell1 is clicked. At present I do  not get any output.

Comment: `.attr("click", true)` doesn't make any sense. There's no attribute for clicks like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    if(this.id=='cell1') alert('cell1 clicked');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uYVQs/1/)**

You need to use the click event, not an attribute (`attr()`). Depending on what you need, you could also just bind directly to the cell with ID of cell1 with `$('#cell1').click(function(){...})`

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery selector has to select proper cell and attach onclick handler to it like such:

```
$('td#cell1').on('click', function(){
    alert('cell1 clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cell1').on('click',function(){
       alert("Cell 1 was clicked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("td#cell1").click(function() {
  alert("Cell 1 was clicked")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is an `ID` I would directly attach it, `attr` is not what you are looking for.

```
$('#cell1').click(function(){
    alert('Cell1 has been clicked!');
});'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `jQuery` code, you need to target your element with its `ID` like that :

```
$('#cell1').click(function(){
    alert('cell1 was clicked');
});
```

If you want to be more general on targeting, do like that instead :

```
$('#my-table td').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name')+' was clicked');
});
```

With this `HTML` code :

```
<table id="my-table" class="tab1" width="400" cellpadding="20">
     <tr>
         <td name="cell1">Name</td>
         <td name="cell2">Company</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

With the second method, you could factorise your bind of `LI` clicks